# OpenGL ES --- on chip

Tags: opengl-es-2.0

[RPi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raspberry_Pi) have -> Chipset BCM2835 -> this chipset have GPU ->  GPU support -> OpenGL ES 2.0

OpenGL is a software library for graphics. What does it mean that full library of OpenGL is implemented in VLSI level on chip inside GPU?

Do we have to do function call to these OpenGL functions in some hardware registers?

Answer (score 0):

I have never done programming for raspberry pi, but i dont think you have to worry about chip level stuff. So long as the chip upholds the opengl functionality standards, you shouldn't have to worry about it. The opengl api is there for making this kind of stuff transparent.